# How to Fetch the sub string between nth occurences of words.?

Tags: php

e.g

main_string = "I have a mango which **<'price'> (abcdef) <'/price'>** 10, a banana which **<'/price'> (ghijk) <'/price'>** 15 and an apple which **<'/price'> (lmnop) <'/price'>** 20. So the total amount spent is Rs 45";

I want to find the substring which is between 3rd occurence of "**<'price'>**" and 3rd occurence of "**<'/price'>**"

i.e output = (lmnop)

**Solution**

**Note :** Here in main string, tag was not coming as string so i kept in quotation like <'price'> and <'/price'>. Solution works only after removing quotes from tag.

Comment: Did you try something? Please include the code that you have tried - have a read of [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I did tried but only able to fetch first occurences ie. (abcdef).

$input = "I have a mango which cost (abcdef) Rs 10, a banana which cost (ghijk) Rs 15 and an apple which cost (lmnop) Rs 20. So the total amount spent is Rs 45";
preg_match('~cost(.*?)Rs~', $input, $output);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = 'I have a mango which <price>1111</price> 10, a banana which <price>3333</price> 15 and an apple which <price>5555</price> 20. So the total amount spent is Rs 45';
$pattern = '/\<price\>(.*?)\<\/price\>/';

$matches = array();

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

var_dump($matches[1][2]);
```

Result is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "<price>1111</price>"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "<price>3333</price>"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "<price>5555</price>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1111"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "3333"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "5555"
  }
}
string(4) "5555" // <-- that's what you want
```

Comment: Its working with "Cost" and "Rs" but if I am replacing "Cost" with "<price>" and "Rs" with "</price>" in main string, its not working. Does this tag making any difference in $pattern.

Comment: @rohit jaiswal Its not mentioned in question. But if you want do that way like in your comment try change pattern to `$pattern = '/\<price\>\((.*?)\)\<\/price\>/';`. Please post what string you exactly working with.

Comment: This is not working. Only I am getting the size of $array but values are empty.

Comment: So part of the string is for example `<price>22</price>`?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. But you should update your question, so there will be mentioned that you need to get string from `price` tags.